# How do I check if Tasker is the application in focus using a Tasker profile?

Tags: tasker

I want to execute a few tasks whenever I am active on Tasker (e.g. editing profiles, viewing settings, etc). However, the problem is I can't see it on the list of applications that's usable when creating a profile. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this wasn't currently possible so I just created a widget that activated whatever profile I want active when Tasker is open then disable the said profile if I go back to the home app.

Answer (score 1):

The developer of Tasker has specifically excluded Tasker itself from showing up in the Applications list.  He cites his reason in the Tasker Why...? section of his website.

http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/faqs/faq-why.html#d